# Watermarking a PDF with another PDF or HTML

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, fpdf, fpdi

Let's say I have **stamp.pdf** or **stamp.html** and **original.pdf**.

**stamp.pdf** (**stamp.html**) contains a stamp and I want to place **stamp.pdf** over **original.pdf** in a certain position and generate a new pdf - **original_stamped.pdf**.

I would like to insert **stamp.pdf** as a pdf (vector graphic) or as html, but not converting to raster image and then insert into **original_stamped.pdf**.

I am talking about stamping or watermarking (over the page), but not just adding an additional page to pdf.

Comment: FPDI...are you there?? http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/

Comment: Robert Rozas: I am aware how to insert text or image into pdf. I am talking about stamping or watermarking (over the page), but not just adding an additional page to pdf. I need to insert a pdf or html. How do I do that with FPDi?

Comment: http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/demos/simple-demo/ ....i think that can be accomplish using fpdi, read the manual and look at the demos.

Comment: I already did that, and I don't see how I can do that.

Comment: $pdf->setSourceFile('PDFDocument.pdf'); that line set the source file(an already created pdf file)...and the other info is stamped over that file and outputed here $pdf->Output('newpdf.pdf', 'D');

Comment: any more details on "...and the other info is stamped over that file"?

Comment: Yes...all the info is stamped over the file....fpdi use a existing pdf as a template....and paste data over it

Comment: I would appreciate to get code for stamping.. I know how to setSourceFile and Output.

Comment: "....and paste data over it" - the problem is that I cannot find a way how to paste data in form of another pdf or html. I only know how to paste it in form of text or image.

Comment: Fpdi uses fpdf class, and fpdf can insert html code to a pdf....you can use a mix of both things

Comment: yes indeed, I tried WriteHTML (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php), but I lost all styling and only pure text remained in pdf...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is something like that:

```
$pdf=new FPDI();
$pdf->addPage();

// Form
$pdf->setSourceFile('form.pdf'); // Specify which file to import
$tplidx = $pdf->importPage(1); // Import first page
$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx,0,0); // Position at 0,0 and use original page size

// Stamp
$pdf->setSourceFile('stamp.pdf'); // Specify which file to import
$tplidx2 = $pdf->importPage(1); // Import first page
$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx2,10,10,($pdf->w / 2)); // Position at 10,10 and resize to 50% of current page width

$pdf->Output();
```